# How to define a variable after process in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use an ajax process to modify user's state on an `index.php` file.

It works but I would like to color my div function of the user's state

**My code:**

```
function recupstatut() {
  $.post('recup.php', function(data) {
    $('.cont2').html(data);

    var content = document.querySelector('#cont2');
    var status2 = content.innerHTML;

    if (status2 == "En-ligne") {
      content.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
    } else {
      content.style.backgroundColor = "#f44336";
    }
  });
}

setInterval(recupstatut, 1000);
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont2" id="cont2">
</div>
```

The condition always applies the else state:

```
content.style.backgroundColor = "#f44336";
```

I think the problem comes from `var status2 =`

How can I fix this?

Comment: do a `console.log(status2)` and see what comes out. Seems to me it will never be `En-ligne`

Comment: You're assigned the return to `.cont` and pulling it out of `#cont2`.

Comment: i will do now the console.log giorgio

Comment: @MCMXCII HTML  : `<div class="cont2" id="cont2">` so he can use # or .
put some `console.log` and with your ajax try to get an JSON and not an HTML.

Comment: Try `status2.trim()` to get rid of any whitespace - although I agree with @Kaddath, use the value directly from the response instead of appending it then selecting it again

Comment: What does your `recup.php` return? a JSON object? If it's that, then just parse this data and put the content in your div. By the way, your `status2` variable equals to `data`, no need to select your original div .

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant Good point. In which case, `console.log` out `data` at the first line of the `$.post` function to make sure you're getting something back.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, it's obvious that it's text sorry, I forgot that he was putting it in a div without touching it.

Comment: console.log(status2) gave me  status2 is not defined

Comment: There's your problem then. Without seeing what the HTML you're returning is we can't really help any further

Comment: no i don't return json this file return echo php in function of the user's state

Comment: You need to put the `console.log(status2)` statement after the one that defines the `status2` variable (after `var status2 = content.innerHTML;`).

Comment: you need to put console.log(data);

Comment: How to use the value diretly from the reponse ?

Comment: $.post('recup.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

Comment: console.log(data) is not defined

Comment: you have to decalre jquery abore

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>function recupstatut() {
  $.post('recup.php', function(data) {
    $('.cont2').html(data);

    var content = document.querySelector('#cont2');
    var status2 = content.innerHTML;

    if (status2 == "En-ligne") {
      content.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
    } else {
      content.style.backgroundColor = "#f44336";
    }
  });
}

setInterval(recupstatut, 1000);

<div class="cont2" id="cont2">
</div>

Comment: All you have to do is call setInterval() after the jquery import

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="cont2" id="cont2"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function recupstatut() {
   $.post('recup.php', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var status2 = data.trim();
      console.log(status2);
      $('.cont2').html(status2);
      if (status2 == "En-ligne") {
         content.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
      } else {
         content.style.backgroundColor = "#f44336";
      } 
  });
}
setInterval(recupstatut, 1000);
</script>
```

what went wrong is that you imported jquery file after calling the function

so make the import in top of calling your function

**your mistake was that you made the import after calling the function, that is why you got undefined error.**

Comment: <div class="cont2" id="cont2"></div>
he is setting and getting data from same DIV

Comment: i posted it from his question

Comment: This is logically identical to what the OP already has - which does not work.

Comment: that is why I have asked him to do a console
console.log(data);
to see what the ajax returns

Comment: Which should be a comment, not an answer - and in fact already is.

Comment: he doesnt know, how to see the output of ajax call. and mine helps him to see the data via console..

Comment: what about now? his mistake was that he made the import after calling the function, that is why he got undefined error.

Comment: i have updated my answer, with console.log(data), after calling $.post(),

Comment: Hope you have got the answer

Comment: no i'm lost with the console.log nothing appear now

Comment: try console.log('['+data + ']');
and see what comes in between the brackets []

Comment: with this code exactly the same i've got no color in my div

Comment: what is the value you are getting in data

Comment: i have use console.log('['+data + ']'); i have the state user in my div but no color

Comment: [ En-ligne  

 ]

[ En-ligne  

 ]

Comment: try console.log('value=*'+data + ']*end of value'); 
and share the console output

Comment: change
          var status2 = data; to
          var status2 = data.trim();

Comment: see my answer I have updated...           var status2 = data.trim();

Comment: yes the color appear and change with the state user !!!!! why data.trim() works ? i just want to understand the mistake !!!

Comment: from your php code.. 
the data is returning with white space ' En-ligne '

`var a = ' En-ligne ';
var b = a.trim();

then b will become 'En-ligne'`

Comment: when you call trim().  the blank spaces after or before the data will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you `echo` string in your page then you can check this one directly from the `data` as per below code.

**Script:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    function recupstatut() {
      $.post('recup.php', function(data) {

        $('#cont2').html(data); // If the data return from the php page as a string then you can compare it directly.

        if (data == "En-ligne") {
          $('#cont2').css("backgroundColor","#4CAF50");
        } else {
          $('#cont2').css("backgroundColor","#f44336"); 
        }

      });

    }

    setInterval(recupstatut, 1000);
});

</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cont2" id="cont2"></div>
```

Comment: no always problem with the data always the else with your code

Comment: What ! Please explain ??

Answer (score 0):

```js
function recupstatut(){
        $.post('recup.php',function(data){
   console.log(data);
            $('.cont2').html(data);
   
   var status2 = data;
 if (status2 == "En-ligne") {
      $('#cont2').css("backgroundColor","#4CAF50");
    } else {
      $('#cont2').css("backgroundColor","#f44336"); 
    }

  });

}
 

 


    setInterval(recupstatut,1000);
```

nothing appear in my div now with the console.log...

Answer (score -1):

THere many ways to accomplish **this**. You can use the **$.post()** function by sending the **$.post** as a variable. Example:

```
// Fire off the request to /form.php
request = $.post({
    url: "recup.php",
});

// Callback handler that will be called on success
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // Log a message to the console
    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
});

// Callback handler that will be called on failure
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // Log the error to the console
    console.error(
        "The following error occurred: "+
        textStatus, errorThrown
    );
});

// Callback handler that will be called regardless
// if the request failed or succeeded
request.always(function () {
    // Reenable the inputs
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Or (**i recommended**) use the **$.ajax({})** function as this way:

```
// Fire off the request to /form.php
$.ajax({
    url: "recup.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { //specify data to be sent },
    beforeSend:function(){ 
      /* before sending the data to the other page 
         may be a loader to show waiting animation
       */
    },
    success:function(status){
      /* this will check the response received from the previous page 
         and the determine the below conditions 
       */
        if (status == "En-ligne") {
        content.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
        } else {
          content.style.backgroundColor = "#f44336";
        }
    }
});
```